# Redmine link to project wiki when name contains spaces

Tags: redmine, wiki

In Redmine docs (https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineTextFormattingTextile) I read

> [[sandbox:]] displays a link to the Sandbox wiki main page

Unfortunately the project I have to link to is named like "ACME - Awesome Project".
I have tried all of these but no one works:

- [[acme-awesome-project:]]
- [[ACME-Awesome-Project:]]
- [[ACME---Awesome-Project:]]
- [["ACME - Awesome Project":]]

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
[[acme_project_identifier:|ACME - Awesome Project]]
```

Where `acme_project_identifier`is what uniquely identifies your project.

Comment: It turned out that our installation is an Easy Redmine one and project identifiers are pure numbers. So `[[<numeric id>:]]` did the trick. Thanks for you help!